# How to simulate tab key with enter key on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, enter

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onDataBound(e) {
            $("#batchgrid").on("click", "td", function (e) {

                $("input").on("keydown", function (event) {
                    if (event.keyCode == 13) {

                        event.keycode=9;
                        return event.keycode;
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
```

here i'm using above script to fire **tab key press event** when i press the **enter key**.but it doesn't behave as tab key pressed when i press the enter key.

please help me here..

Comment: did any of these proposed answers work for you?

Answer (score 1):

`return event.keycode` is effectively `return 9`, and even `return event` will not help, as returning the event does not mean that will be handled properly, what you probably want to do instead is to take the `enter` event and then manually change focus to the next required field:

```
function onDataBound(e) {
  $("#batchgrid").on("click", "td", function (e) {
    $("input").on("keydown", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).next("input, textarea").focus()
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not simulate until you prevent the default enter key event.
event.preventDefault(); should be the first command of your function.Then implement the tab key event.Your code should be something like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onDataBound(e) {
        $("#batchgrid").on("click", "td", function (e) {

            $("input").on("keydown", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                if (event.keyCode == 13) {

                    event.keycode=9;
                    return event.keycode;
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Hope it will work.