# Swap Enter Key for Tab Key

Tags: javascript, asp.net

So I've got this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnKeyPress() {
        var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
        if (charCode == 13) {                
            window.event.keyCode = 9;
        }
    } document.onkeypress = OnKeyPress;
</script>
```

The idea is to catch an enter key press, and switch it to tab key press. And it half works - it catches the enter key. But it doesn't make it register as a tab key. I've tried using other keycodes as well (18 for alt) to confirm I wasn't just not seeing the tab happen.

Can anyone see what the problem is? Working in ASP.NET fwiw.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the keyCode and have it trigger that event instead.  It's just a captured value at that point.  You might be able to obtain the effect by calling a function that simulates the desired key press event and canceling the current event instead.

Comment: so you're suggesting dropping this bit 'window.event.keyCode = 9;
' and replacing it with a function call? Can you recommend a function that would produce the desired result?

Comment: Depends on what the desired results are.  There's actually a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482036/how-to-simulate-tab-key-with-enter-key-on-javascript   Is that what you are trying to do also?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create the event handler for it.

Take a look:

[How to trigger event in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)

Comment: If you're in a hurry you can use jQuery to do it. Use the .trigger function.

It will be a lot simpler, but doing it in pure javascript is far better from the learning perspective.

;)