# Make enter button act as tab ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am currently trying to make the enter button tab across all of the user controls in my website. Although I do not want to have to rename every control on my site to: "control1, control2, etc.." and itterate through them this way.

This is the code that I currently have:

```
    function enterToTab(e) {
    var intKey = window.Event ? e.which : e.KeyCode;

    //If the key that is pushed is the enter key we will not submit.
    if (intKey == 13)
    {
        e.KeyCode = 9;
        e.returnValue = false;
    }
}
```

Then inside the master page asp I have this:

```
<body onkeydown="enterToTab(event);">
```

Currently my code will not tab, but it will prevent the page from re-submitting when the user presses enter. Any extra thoughts or ideas will be appreciated.

Also, I do not have a Jquery library so this should be in javascript.

Comment: You cannot set the keyCode. It's get only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to simulate tab key with enter key on javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482036/how-to-simulate-tab-key-with-enter-key-on-javascript)

Comment: That is using Jquery I do not have the library for that.